# Is there a combinatorial proof of this congruence identity?

Tags: number-theory, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Prove that
$$\binom{2p}{p} \equiv 2\pmod{p^3},$$
where $p\ge 5$ is a prime number.

Comment: It's easy to prove it by algebraic method, but I am very interested to find a combinatorial interpretation of it.

Comment: This congruence identity can be generalized as follows$${ap \choose bp} \equiv {a \choose b} \pmod{p^3},$$ where $p$ is a prime number and $a,b$ are positive integers. The combinatorial proof of it can be reduce to the case $a=2,b=1$.

Answer (score 8):

A combinatorial proof for the congruence $\bmod p^2$ is given at [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26137/binomial-supercongruences-is-there-any-reason-for-them) but the answerer suggests the congruence $\bmod p^3$ does not have a natural combinatorial proof.

Comment: Have you read the bottom of that answer?

Comment: Yes.  What about it?

Comment: Thank to QiaoChu Yuan very much. Indeed, there is a more general result, which have a beautiful combinatorial proof, for the congruence mod $p^2$ as follows  $${ ap \choose bp}  \equiv { a \choose b } \pmod {p^2}, $$ wherer $p$ is a prime number and $a, b$ are positive integers.